# UialertController to show only once when the var hits an certain Value

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

so the way my app works is you tap on a cell , a var value gets modified (+1 for example). I've figured out how to get a UIalert to pop when my var reaches a certain value (10). But now everytime I update the var the alert pops. What i would like it to do is to pop when the var hits 10 and stop after that

Heres the code :

```
    if (section1score >= 10){
        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Section 1 score is over 10", comment: ""),
            message: " \(message1)",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
            action -> Void in }

        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } 

if (section2score >= 10){
        let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Section 2 Score is over 10", comment: ""),
            message: "\(message2)",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
            action -> Void in }

        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: modified it as  `if section1score == 10 { `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a `Bool` to check if the alert has been shown or not. Create the `Bool` globally and set it to `false` initially.

```
var showedAlert = false

func yourFunction() {
    if section1score >= 10 && showedAlert == false {
        // show alert
        showedAlert = true
    }

    if section2score >= 10 && showedAlert == false {
        // show alert
        showedAlert = true
    }
}
```

[**Comparison Operators**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID70)

Comment: thing is the app is likely never goind to hit 10 exactly, mostly gonna jump from 8 to 12

Comment: @Jp4Real I've updated my answer. Create the `Bool` globally and set it to `false` initially.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a property to keep track of when you show the alert so that once you show it, you won't show it again.

```
var hasShownAlert: Bool = false

if (section1score >= 10 && !hasShownAlert){
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Section 1 score is over 10", comment: ""),
        message: " \(message1)",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
        action -> Void in }

    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    hasShownAlert = true
} 

if (section2score >= 10 && !hasShownAlert){
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Section 2 Score is over 10", comment: ""),
        message: "\(message2)",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) {
        action -> Void in }

    alertController.addAction(OKAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    hasShownAlert = true
}
```

Comment: now when i set bool:false, it still pops all the time, but when i set true it does not pop at all... maybe im not declaring my var at the right place ??

Comment: Did you just one `&` instead of two `&&`?

Comment: @keithbhunter sounds like hes putting `var hasShownAlert: Bool = false` inside his function. This needs to be created globally and set initially to `false`.